# Angular directive doesn't display after returning to page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am writing an Ionic app and I'm having trouble with a custom directive element.

Here's a simplified codepen of my problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGJRQg

```
angular.module('ionicApp',[
  'ionic'
])

.directive('map', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

            function drawMap(position) {

                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

                scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map
                });

                scope.map = map;
            }

            function updateMap(position) {
                var newPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
                scope.marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                scope.map.panTo(newPosition);
            }

            var position = {
        coords: {
          latitude: 50.2440218,
          longitude: 5.2807709
        }
      };

            scope.currentPosition = position.coords;

      if (!scope.map) {
        drawMap(position.coords);
      } else {
        updateMap(position.coords);
      }

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                watch.clearWatch();
            });


        },
        template: '<div style="width: 100%; height: 280px;" id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>'
    }
});
```

If you click the 'search for a job code' button, it takes you to the search page. When you're on this page, if you click the back button in the top left corner, the map on the first page still displays OK. However if you click the 'select job code' button, you are redirected back to the original page but the map isn't visible.

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help

Edit: I have noticed that if I don't include any params, like so:

```
$scope.selectJobCode = function(jobCode) {
    $state.go('app.jobs');
};
```

then the directive remains intact and working. However as soon as I send params along with the state change, the directive doesn't work anymore:

```
$scope.selectJobCode = function(jobCode) {
    $state.go('app.jobs', {
        jobCode: jobCode
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using $stateParams, I have temporarily used the $rootScope and $watch, which now works OK:

In the app.jobs-search controller:

```
$scope.selectJobCode = function(jobCode) {
    $rootScope.selectedJobCode = jobCode;
    $state.go('app.jobs');
};
```

and in the app.jobs controller:

```
$rootScope.$watch('selectedJobCode', function() {
    if ($rootScope.selectedJobCode) {
        $scope.selectedJobCode = $rootScope.selectedJobCode;
        delete $rootScope.selectedJobCode;
    }
});
```

This solution suits my needs but I'm still curious as to why the directive problem occurs with my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about i can't write comment. So i think your problem is about

```
<ion-view view-title="Jobs Search">
```

and

```
<ion-view view-title="Jobs">
```

Your first tab and last tab has same title. Maybe you can try with change one of them.Your back button is navigating with view-title i think.

Comment: Changing the title doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: hmm sorry then. I thinked only this for now :(

Answer (score 0):

can you double check whether the JSON input you send to **$scope.selectJobCode function** is correct?

commenting this line below in **selectJobCode function**  is making your program to work perfectly on click of **select job code** button

```
// $ionicHistory.backView().stateParams = {jobCode:jobCode}; 

Js code
.state('app.jobs-search', {
            url: "/jobs/search",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/jobs-search.html",
                    controller: function($scope, $ionicHistory) {
             $scope.selectJobCode = function(jobCode) {
              // $ionicHistory.backView().stateParams = {jobCode:jobCode};
                      $ionicHistory.goBack();
             };
          }
                }
            }
        })
```

**Updated1:**

use below code. it works fine now.

```
$ionicHistory.backView().stateParams = [{"jobCode":jobCode}];
```

instead of this

```
$ionicHistory.backView().stateParams = {jobCode:jobCode};
```

**Updated2:**

You can use the angular inbuilt scope variable $scope to access watch function on any user defined object or variable.

```
$scope.$watch(theObjectUWantToWatch, function(new){
      console.log('new value is ' + new);
    });
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine if you don't update the stateParams, it's the same with using $state.go in my edited question. The content of the jobCode variable is fine.

Comment: @Daniel7912  dude, i think its the JSON problem in selectJobCode function. check my updated answer

Comment: That redirects back to the original page OK, but how do I grab the stateParams value? $stateParams doesn't have a $watch function.

Comment: You can use the angular inbuilt scope variable $scope to access watch function on any user defined object or variable..i have updated the answer with a snippet